# less detailed math proof naming

Tags: proof-writing, terminology

I am looking for a math term in English meaning something like a less perfect mathematical proof. For example:

1. first proof

$f(n)=1+2+...+n$

$f(n)=n+(n-1)+...+1$

=============

$2f(n)=(n+1)+(n+1)+...+(n+1)$

hence

$f(n)=n(n+1)/2$

while a formal proof would be:

2. second proof

$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k$

$f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1)$

=============

$2f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k+\sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1)$

$2f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n [k+(n-k+1)]$

$2f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n [(n+1)]$

$2f(n)=[n(n+1)]$

$f(n)=[n(n+1)]/2$

2. is a formal proof, what is 1. called in English?

suggestion: imperfect demonstration

Thank you.

Comment: You could say "informal" or "less formal".

Comment: I am not really sure what distinction you are looking for, and I also think that the distinction is not as clear as you seem to think.  The level of "rigor" or "formality" of a proof is largely a function of who the intended audience is.  That being said, you might(?) be looking for the terms "sketch", "outline", or "heuristic".

Comment: In the example 1. I provided one can say that the three dots can contain other terms that are not clear how they look like. While in 2. every term is described in the sum. I found that a proof is an unequivocal demonstration. What should I call 1. then?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: OK. I am looking for a math term in English meaning a type of demonstration that is less perfect or less detailed mathematical proof involving adding terms in "three dots" as opposite in a formal proof containing expressions for every term instead of the mentioned "three dots". Thank you.

Comment: I use the word *heuristic*, but I don’t find the use of $\dots$ unrigorous. I would require words in both proofs. Writing a sea of symbols does not make good mathematics.

Comment: In both proofs we are adding two equations, in the second equation the order of items is reversed.

Answer (score 1):

A formal proof has a meaning in logic, see for example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_proof. You rarely if ever want to think about formal proofs unless you are studying foundational maths/ encoding things in lean etc and I wouldn't call either of your proofs a formal proof. Typically, a formal proof of an interesting fact is very long, and in my experience is often not something a human wants to read.

Most working mathematicians don't care about formal proof in the above sense. Instead a good definition of a proof is something (anything: a picture, a paragraph, some algebraic manipulations) which will convince a competent but suspicious/hostile reader that the claim is true.

In my mind the two proofs you gave are the same. That is because the mathematical ideas in them are precisely the same and a competent reader understands the same thing from both. The only difference is the second proof uses different notation and spells out intermediate steps.

So to answer your question: these are the same proof. To articulate the difference I would say: the notation in the first version is more elementary, the second gives more detail on intermediate steps. In general a proof which is not satisfactory (because it does not convince a competent reader but has the right idea) might be called "sloppy" or "unclear" or if it was intended then a "proof sketch".

A word of warning on proof snobbery: in some sense Godel's incompleteness theorem is telling you that you can't be *perfectly rigorous*, whatever perfectly rigorous means.

Comment: Godel's incompleteness theorem says that in every axiomatic system there will be at least one theorem that will be not possible to prove using the means from that system. It doesn't mean that a proof of a theorem cannot be rigorous if such a theorem is provable in that system.

Comment: Rephrasing what you said: Godel is telling you that you cannot prove an axiomatic system is consistent within that system. You can now go give a rigorous proof of a theorem, but if you don't know your system is consistent then what does your proof even mean? If the system is inconsistent then you can prove "false" and if you can prove false you can prove every statement.